# Developing asp.net on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, windows-server

I have been asked to make some changes to an asp.net website but i only have access to a macbook air and no applicable servers.  I don't have the disk space to install windows server on parallels and have tried following the instructions in the link below.

https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-mac-os-x/

I could get the console app to run but the web app threw up a bunch of errors.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?  Maybe a free trial for a cloud based windows server or some other way of deploying the site so i can see my changes?

Thanks for any help

Richard.

Comment: You will have to find a Windows machine. Classic ASP.NET apps are only supported on Windows while the new ASP.NET Core can develop and run on Mac.

Comment: [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) offers free hosting (for some time) and you can deploy apps there.